# Given ${[1+x^2 , 1+x-x^3]} \subseteq U\cap W $, Find $\dim(U+W) , \dim(U\cap W) ,\dim(U)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U,W$ be two subspaces of $R_3[x]$ so that $U\neq W$ and $\dim(U)=\dim(W)$

Given ${[1+x^2 , 1+x-x^3]} \subseteq U\cap W $, find $\dim(U+W) , \dim(U\cap W) , \dim(U)$.

If the vectors are in the intersection subspace, they are linear combinations of  the basis vectors of $U$ and $W$.

How to proceed from here?

Comment: What's $R_3[x]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $R_3[x]$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 3$. This is a four dimensional vector space.

Suppose that $U\cap W$ had dimension four. Then, $U=W=U\cap V=R_3[x]$, which is a contradiction since $U\neq V$.

Suppose that $U\cap W$ had dimension three. Since $U\neq W$, we must have that $U$ or $W$ contains some element not in $U\cap V$. Hence, one of $U$ or $W$ has dimension $\geq 4$. However, $R_3[x]$ is four dimensional and hence this would imply $U=W=R_3[x]$ is three dimensional.

Thus, $U\cap W$ is two dimensional.

Now, we know that $U$ or $W$ have an element not in $U\cap W$. Hence, $U$ and $W$ are either both $3$ dimensional or both $4$ dimensional. Again, if they are both four dimensional then $U=W=R_3[x]$. Thus, $U$ and $W$ are both three dimensional.

Thus, $U$ and $W$ are non-equal $3$ dimensional spaces. Thus, $U+W$ must properly contain $U$ and $V$, thus must be four dimensional.

In summary: $\dim(U+W)=4$, $\dim(U\cap W)=2$, and $\dim(U)=3$.

Comment: Thanks. I see you actually solved it without using  ${[1+x^2 , 1+x-x^3]} \subseteq U\cap W $. Is there a way to solve the question using it?  So I could know what to do with that for future questions

Comment: I'm using that fact that $U\cap W$ is at least 2 dimensional: That's why its important that $[1+x^2,1+x-x^3]$